# Pine Script: Deactivate display of number(s) when using plotshapes

Tags: pine-script

as I use several plotshapes I would like to know if it is possible to deactivate the display of the corresponding numbers next to the used script displayed within the chart for particular plotshapes?

To better understand what I mean, please check the highlighted area with the numbers in this picture:

[image: Plotshape Numbers]

I want to do this as the displayed number for each plotshape does not make any sense for my purposes (they stay on zero as I use the plotshapes to display text/symbol information only, e.g. for a morning star or inverted hammer, etc.).

Perhaps I should use another way to display that information but I have no idea, how. The script is as follows, e.g. to display a hammer:

```
hammer = (((high - low)>3*(open - close)) and ((close - low)/(.001 + high - low) > 0.6) and ((open - low)/(.001 + high - low) > 0.6))
plotshape(hammer, title="Hammer", text="H", color=#006000, style=shape.diamond, location=location.belowbar, editable=false)
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Pine as far as I know.
Every value you put on the chart will automatically be shown next to the script name and in the data window.
No matter which method you choose, wether it is `plot`, `plotchar`, `plotshape`, `plotarrow` etc.., the value will always be shown.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad.

Comment: I just found out that what you're asking for is currently being considered for development by the Pine team. They're looking to add more options to the `display` parameter of `plot`, `plotchar`, `plotshape`, etc... than the currently available `display.all` and `display.none`. Not sure when it'll be developed though.

Comment: Sounds great. In the meantime I found a not perfect solution: just add an `if then else` within the first `plot` parameter, like:

`plotshape(morning_star?true:na, ...)`

Then it is displayed only on a mouse-over when the corresponding variable is true for the actual candle.